# symbolic link can only be created from parent to child under FreeBSD?

Tags: symlink, freebsd, ln

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-XosJtC0vyA

In the current directory(test), I have used

```
echo date > date.sh ; chmod u+x date.sh
```

to create date.sh and make it executable.

Then I used

```
ln -s date.sh ../date.sh.sym1
ln -s ./date.sh ../date.sh.sym2
```

to create two symbolic links in the parent directory from which I typed

```
./date.sh.sym1
./date.sh.sym2
```

The result was that both showed command not found.
Then in the parent directory, I used

```
ln -s test/date.sh date.sh.sym3
```

to create another symlink. This time it becomes executable after I typed

```
./date.sh.sym3
```

Is it because symlink can only be created from parent to child ? (FreeBSD 10.2)

Answer (score 1):

The user in the video typed the ln commands incorrectly. The first parameter to ln is the target (what you're linking to) the second paramter is where the place the link. When you do `ln -s date.sh ../date.sh.sym1` you're placing a symlink in the parent directory to something in the current directory. The user in the video then changed directories to the parent directory. From that frame of reference the OS was expecting something called `date.sh` in the current directory. Hence the `command not found` errors.

The second ln, `ln -s test/date.sh date.sh.sym3` created a link to `test/date.sh`. That path (`test/date.sh`) could be resolved, which is why it ran.